# Capture data from website

Tags: powershell

This website http://www.ariacharts.com.au/chart/singles   I am trying to use Invoke-WebRequest to get the top 50 songs from it, there are two classes throughout **class="item-title"** and **class="artist-name"** I need to get the elements to gather the right information.

```
$top50raw1 = Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.ariacharts.com.au/chart/singles"
```

Then I use:

```
$top50raw1.ParsedHtml
```

There is a choice of **getElementById**, **getElementsByName** and **getElementsByTagName** along with IDs **dvChartListingContainer** and **dvChartItems**

Even using either of:

```
$top50raw1.ParsedHtml.getElementById('dvChartItems')
$top50raw1.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div')
```

Doesn't work, I am not sure how to use the correct elements in the website to capture the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out a different way, using a conglomerate of Internet Explorer and RexEx.

```
$titles = $null
$artists = $null
$ie = New-Object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate('http://www.ariacharts.com.au/chart/singles')
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$rawtop50 = $ie | Select -ExpandProperty document
$titles += $rawtop50.getElementById('dvChartItems').innerHTML | Select-String -Pattern 'title="(.*?)"' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
$artists += $rawtop50.getElementById('dvChartItems').innerHTML | Select-String -Pattern 'artist-name[\s\S]*?data-reactid="[\s\S]*?">(.*?)<\/' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}

$top50 = 0..49 | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Position = $_ + 1 
        Song = $artists[$_] + " - " + $titles[$_]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using InternetExplorer.Application did resolve your issue of not finding the 'DIV' content in the ParsedHtml of the Invoke-WebRequest. But I do find that the way you are collecting your data, is somewhat inefficient. Calling 'getElementByID' twice, and then doing a loop of the arrays to gather them together seems 'iffy'..

In my opinion, looking at one 'row/ranking' at a time, to properly collect the Rank/Artist/Title, guarantees that the data belongs to one another. Also, it speeds up the process.

I did a Measure-Command on your script, versus mine, and i come to ~3.5 seconds for mine, vs 5.5 seconds for yours on average.

Hope this help you or anyone else looking to parse HTML content.

```
$ie = New-Object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate('http://www.ariacharts.com.au/chart/singles')

While ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

$ChartItems = ($ie.Document).getElementByID('dvChartItems')

ForEach ($Row in $ChartItems.childNodes) {

    $Rank = $Row.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].outerText
    $Title = $Row.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].outerText
    $Artist = $Row.childNodes[2].childNodes[1].outerText

    [PSCustomObject]@{ Rank = $Rank; Title = $Title; Artist = $Artist }

}
```

Comment: Thanks i appreciate that, you're using the tables on the site, which is what i was trying to do at the very beginning but couldn't

Comment: Glad i could help! Let me know if you end up using my code, out of curiosity.. ;)

Comment: I needed to use the table method on something else the other day, again i got stuck so resorted to RegEx, i might try your script as a base template and see if that works.